# Android: Promo Codes for Subscriptions?

Tags: android, subscription, promotion-code

Recently, Apple began allowing the creation of promo-codes for in-app subscriptions. I know Android allows promo codes for one-time in-app **purchases**, But I do not know if Android allows promo codes for in-app **subscriptions**.

For example, I know I can offer promo codes for a one-time in-app purchase like an in-game currency. But can I offer promo codes for subscriptions like, say, Tinder Plus.

I'm reading about Android subscriptions [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html), and about promo-codes [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html), but nowhere does it discuss promo-codes for subscriptions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer for this one: No.

I just tried it out for you and and received the following message when clicking <kbd>Get</kbd>

> Subscriptions aren't eligible for promotions.

Comment: That's a shame... Thanks for testing it!

Comment: You could always create a special item just for this purpose and check if sub is active or if that special item is active in the code... and if both are active, refund the current months sub (then next time the app checks, the sub wont show as active I believe). But you have to then also remove the special item when the sub should resume.... way too many places for failure for my liking

Comment: @NickCardoso still promo codes not eligible for subscriptions?

Comment: I wonder if you could have a promo code that tells app to move the user to a subscription with a free trial for a month - effectively being a discount.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried promo codes for subscription and it works. But you can give a maximum of 90 days free. It's not the same as iOS subscription promo codes.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed possible, as you can read in the [google documentations](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promo):

> Promotions, or promo codes, let you give one-time products or trials to subscriptions free-of-charge to a limited number of users.

But for subscriptions, note the following:

> - Promo codes offer free trials to subscriptions and not free subscriptions.
> - Promotions do not extend other free trials. If a subscription begins with a free trial without requiring a promo code, a promotion would override the original free trial length.
> - Users who aren't eligible for non-promo free trials—for example, users who have already purchased a subscription in the past—are still eligible for a free trial through a promotion.

And referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57003217/5093841), promotions for subscriptions can only be set to a maximum of 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can have one time codes and custom codes for subscriptions as well as one time products.
Just navigate to **Play Console > Your App > User Acquisition > Promotions > Add New Promotion > Choose subscription**. That's it!!

Answer (score -1):

promo codes can’t be used for subscriptions as per the tips from [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/create-promo-codes-for-your-apps-and-in.html). [image]

Comment: this is old blog from 2016, now google recommend it